# Raspberry Pi3 and android app bluetooth sending messages but not receiving

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I am building an app that connects to a raspberry pi3 through bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). I got both devices to connect, and android app is able to send messages to RPi but the android app does not receive messages at all (Meaning onDataReceived is never called). For the Android connection I used SPPLibrary https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary .

I think there might be a format issue or something like that because I tried with a bluetooth terminal sample app at the store and it is working perfectly.

My android code:

```
public class TerminalActivity extends Activity {
BluetoothSPP bt;

TextView textStatus, textRead;

Menu menu;

Iteration [] schedules;
String TAG = "developer";
String device_name;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminal);

    textRead = findViewById(R.id.textRead);
    textStatus = findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

    bt = new BluetoothSPP(this);

    if(!bt.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                , "Bluetooth is not available"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new OnDataReceivedListener() {
        public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {
           textRead.append(message + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(TerminalActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    bt.setBluetoothConnectionListener(new BluetoothConnectionListener() {
        public void onDeviceDisconnected() {
            textStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            textStatus.setText("Status : Not connect");
            menu.clear();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_connection, menu);
        }

        public void onDeviceConnectionFailed() {
            textStatus.setText("Status : Connection failed");
        }

        public void onDeviceConnected(String name, String address){
            textStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            device_name = name;
            textStatus.setText("Status : Connected to " + name);
            menu.clear();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_disconnection, menu);
        }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_connection, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.menu_device_connect) {
        bt.setDeviceTarget(BluetoothState.DEVICE_OTHER);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
    } else if(id == R.id.menu_disconnect) {
        if(bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED)
            bt.disconnect();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.schedule) {
        if(bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScheduleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("schedules",schedules);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    bt.stopService();
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!bt.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        if(!bt.isServiceAvailable()) {
            bt.setupService();
            bt.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_ANDROID);
            setup();
        }
    }
}

public void setup() {
    Button btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED)
                bt.send("shoot", false);
            else
                Toast.makeText(TerminalActivity.this, "Sorry, you need to connect first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            bt.connect(data);
    } else if(requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            bt.setupService();
            bt.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_ANDROID);
            setup();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Bluetooth was not enabled."
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}

My RPi python3 code:`

```
# Importing the Bluetooth Socket library
import bluetooth
# Importing the GPIO library to use the GPIO pins of Raspberry pi
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import threading
import time


led_pin = 16    # Initializing pin 40 for led
fan_pin = 13
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Using BCM numbering
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)   # Declaring the pin 40 as output pin
GPIO.setup(fan_pin, GPIO.OUT)
host = ""
port = 1    # Raspberry Pi uses port 1 for Bluetooth Communication
# Creaitng Socket Bluetooth RFCOMM communication
server = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
print('Bluetooth Socket Created')
interval = 15
duration = 5  #in seconds
nextShoot = datetime.datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=interval);
schedule_running = False

def sch_timer(interval):
    print("New thread created")
    global schedule_running
    schedule_running = True
    nextShoot = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=interval)
    print("The next shoot will happen : "+str(nextShoot))
    while schedule_running == True:
        if datetime.datetime.now() > nextShoot:
                print("Schedule shoot!!" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                GPIO.output(led_pin, True)
                #print("LED will be up until: "+str(datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=duration)))
                print(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                print(str(datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=duration)))
                time.sleep(duration)
                GPIO.output(led_pin, False)
                print("duration has expired, new scheduled shoot is at: " + str(datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=interval)))
                nextShoot = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=interval)
    print("End of thread")      
    return

class Schedule():
    def __init__(self):
            try:  #to connect
                    server.bind((host, port))
                    print("Bluetooth Binding Completed")
            except:
                    print("Bluetooth Binding Failed")
            server.listen(1) # One connection at a time
            # Server accepts the clients request and assigns a mac address.
            client, address = server.accept()
            print("Connected To", address)
            print("Client:", client)
            t1 = threading.Thread()
        #   try:
            while True:
                    # Receivng the data.
                    data = client.recv(1024) # 1024 is the buffer size.
                    data = str(data,"utf-8")
                    print(data)

                    if data == "shoot":  #calculate good time to trigger with fans and adjust
                            GPIO.output(led_pin, True) #trigger pin
                            GPIO.output(fan_pin, True)
                            send_data = "Fan On \n"
                    elif data == "release":
                            GPIO.output(led_pin, False)
                            GPIO.output(fan_pin, False)
                            send_data = "Fan Off"
                    elif data == "1min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 1 minute"
                            interval = 1 #in minutes
                     #      dateAndTimeString = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()
                     #      date,time = dateAndTimeString #split date and time into two strings (date and time)
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()

                    elif data == "2min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 2 minutes"
                            interval = 2 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "5min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 5 minutes"
                            interval = 5 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "10min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 10 minutes"
                            interval = 10 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "15min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 15 minutes"
                            interval = 15 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "30min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 30 minutes"
                            interval = 30 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "45min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 45 minutes"
                            interval = 45 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "60min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 60 minutes"
                            interval = 60 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "90min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 90 minutes"
                            interval = 90 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    elif data == "120min":
                            send_data = "Schedule 120 minutes"
                            interval = 120 #in minutes
                            global schedule_running
                            if schedule_running == False:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                            else:
                                print("Thread is currently running, waiting for it to end")
                                schedule_running = False
                                t1.join()
                                print("Past thread is dead, creating new thread...")
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=sch_timer, args=(interval,))
                                t1.start()
                    else:
                            send_data = "Command not recognized. "
                    # Sending the data.
                    #TODO Maybe encode data to UTF-8 before sending
                    client.send(send_data+"\n")
            #~ except:
                    #~ # Making all the output pins LOW
                    #~ GPIO.cleanup()
                    #~ # Closing the client and server connection
                    #~ client.close()
                    #~ server.close()

def main():
    sch = Schedule()

main()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! I was right, just had to append "\r\n" to the end of the message to be sent (send_data). For example: if I wanted to send the message  I would need to do

```
send_data = "Fan Off\r\n"
client.send(send_data)
```